# Is it possible to install MediaWiki on iOS 5

Tags: ipad, mediawiki

I'm looking to run mediawiki on my Mac. It would be great to be able to synchonise with an install on my iPad 3 (currently jailbroken). I therefore need to install mediawiki on my iPad. Is this possible?

If so, how?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question.  Can you install PHP and a web server on your iPad?  (According to [this post](http://www.ipadforums.net/ipad-hacking/24007-running-php-server-ipad.html), maybe you can.)  If yes, you can most likely install MediaWiki too, since it's just a big PHP script.  The [usual install instructions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aInstallation_guide) should work more or less as given, possibly with some adjustments to accommodate any quirks of your web server.

Oh yes, you'll also need an SQL database on your iPad.  It looks like [SQLite](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aSQLite) might work.

If you do get it working, please let us know.  I'm not sure what MediaWiki on an iPad would be good for, but it sure would be cool to know that it's possible. :)